# Applying a cutoff value to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to apply a threshold to 1 column in a 2D tensor. Any value below the cutoff would be listed as `null` or `zero`. I have tried to avoid looping through the tensor and I want the input & output tensor to have the same shape.

Here is the code:

```
NFValue = tf.Variable(1.,dtype=tf.float64,constraint=lambda t: tf.clip_by_value(t, 10, 20))

col1 = tf.gather(x, [0], axis=0)
col2 = tf.gather(x, [1], axis=0)

y = tf.fill(tf.shape(col2), NFValue)   # creates a tensor of the same size as X, with Cutoff
y = tf.cast(y, np.float32)             # converts that tensor into the correct type for comparision.

NewCol2 = tf.boolean_mask(col2, tf.math.greater(col2, y))

return tf.concat([col1[0,:], NewCol2], axis=0)
```

The problem is that `tf.boolean_mask()` returns a tensor with just the values which were greater than `NFValue`. So the shape has changed.  `tf.Greater` will return a boolean vector of the correct shape, but I would need to loop through the tensor.

I have tried several different options around this. I have looked at slice, `tf.Scan` and a couple different functions. I am expecting there to be a canned solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.where`

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.reshape(tf.range(9), (3, 3))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])>
```

```
tf.where(x > 5, x, 0)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8]])>
```